# Passing a class as argument which has a private constructor that takes no parameters

Tags: c++, class, parameters, constructor, arguments

`Simulator` is supposed to carry a copy of `Missile` object inside it. But `Missile` has no public constructor with zero parameters, so I'm not able to pass it as parameter.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, and it gives the following errors:

> Error 1 c:...\simulator.cpp Line #5
>   error C2248: 'Missile::Missile' :
>   cannot access private member declared
>   in class 'Missile'
>
> Error 2 c:...\simulator.cpp Line #4
>   IntelliSense: "Missile::Missile()"
>   (declared at line 11 of
>   "c:...\Missile.h") is inaccessible

So, how do I pass object of a class who has private constructor as argument?

(Note: My code has no entry point. I'm just trying to compile this as a library.)

**Missile.h**

```
#ifndef MISSILE_H
#define MISSILE_H

class Missile
{
    public:
        Missile(double xm0, double ym0, double Vmx0, double Vmy0);
        ~Missile();

    private:
        Missile();                      // Line #11
};

#endif
```

**Missile.cpp**

```
#include "Missile.h"

Missile::Missile(double xm0, double ym0, double Vmx0, double Vmy0)
{
}

Missile::Missile()
{
}

Missile::~Missile()
{
}
```

**Simulator.h**

```
#ifndef SIMULATOR_H
#define SIMULATOR_H

#include "Missile.h"

class Simulator
{
    public:
        Simulator(const Missile & missile);
        ~Simulator();

    private:
        Missile m_Missile;
};

#endif
```

**Simulator.cpp**

```
#include "Simulator.h"

Simulator::Simulator(const Missile & missile)
{                                       // Line #4
    m_Missile = missile;                    // Line #5
}

Simulator::~Simulator()
{
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would use what's called a `ctor-initializer` (some people call it an "initializer list", although the C++ standard actually calls it a "ctor-initializer"):

```
// In your Simulator.cpp file:
Simulator::Simulator(const Missile & missle) : m_Missile(missle)   
                                            /*^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^*/
                                            /* This part here */
{
    /* No assignment needed */
}
```

This is equivalent to calling the *copy constructor* of the `Missile` class, which is automatically generated for you by the compiler, and all it does is copy each data member:

```
class Missile
{
public:
    Missile(double xm0, double ym0, double Vmx0, double Vmy0);
    ~Missile();

    // Compiler generated copy constructor
    Missile(const Missile& rhs) /* copies each data member */
    {
    }

    // Compiler generated copy assignment operator
    Missile& operator=(const Missile& rhs)
    {
        /* copies each data member */
    } 

private:
    Missile(); // default constructor
};
```

Note that the `Simulator` class would also have the compiler-generated copy constructor and the copy assignment operator as well.

Without the `c-tor initializer`, the `Missile` member would be *default initialized* instead, which would call the default constructor, which you have declared to be `private`.

[You should always use `c-tor initializer`s when you can](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6), since it is much more general than assigning to member variables in the constructor.

This is actually a rather fundamental concept in C++, and any [good book on C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) would cover constructors and compiler-generated functions.

Comment: Now, after using ctor-initializer, should I remove the `m_Missile = missile` line inside `Simulator::Simulator()`?

Comment: @hkBattousai: Yes. There's no need to use assignment when you have already copied the object via the compiler-generated copy constructor.